# AES File Encryption not working in C++/CLI

Tags: .net, encryption, c++-cli

I'm trying to AES-encrypt a file. Did a search and found [this C# sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9237606/6204331). This is my attempt to convert it to C++/CLI.

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::IO;
using namespace System::Security::Cryptography;

void DecryptFile(String^ sourceFilename, String^ destinationFilename, String^ password, array<Byte>^ salt, int iterations){
try{
    RijndaelManaged^ aes = gcnew RijndaelManaged();
    aes->BlockSize = aes->LegalBlockSizes[0]->MaxSize;
    aes->KeySize = aes->LegalKeySizes[0]->MaxSize;
    // NB: Rfc2898DeriveBytes initialization and subsequent calls to   GetBytes   must be eactly the same, including order, on both the encryption and decryption sides.
    Rfc2898DeriveBytes ^key = gcnew Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt, iterations);
    aes->Key = key->GetBytes(aes->KeySize / 8);
    aes->IV = key->GetBytes(aes->BlockSize / 8);
    aes->Mode = CipherMode::CBC;
    ICryptoTransform^ transform = aes->CreateDecryptor(aes->Key, aes->IV);

    FileStream^ destination = gcnew FileStream(destinationFilename, FileMode::OpenOrCreate, FileAccess::Write, FileShare::None);
    CryptoStream^ cryptoStream = gcnew CryptoStream(destination, transform, CryptoStreamMode::Write);
    FileStream^ source = gcnew FileStream(sourceFilename, FileMode::Open, FileAccess::Read, FileShare::Read);
    source->CopyTo(cryptoStream);
}
catch (Exception^ exception){Console::WriteLine(exception->Message);}
}

void EncryptFile(String^ sourceFilename, String^ destinationFilename, String^ password, array<Byte>^ salt, int iterations){
try{
    RijndaelManaged^ aes = gcnew RijndaelManaged();
    aes->BlockSize = aes->LegalBlockSizes[0]->MaxSize;
    aes->KeySize = aes->LegalKeySizes[0]->MaxSize;
    // NB: Rfc2898DeriveBytes initialization and subsequent calls to   GetBytes   must be eactly the same, including order, on both the encryption and decryption sides.
    Rfc2898DeriveBytes^ key = gcnew Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt, iterations);
    aes->Key = key->GetBytes(aes->KeySize / 8);
    aes->IV = key->GetBytes(aes->BlockSize / 8);
    aes->Mode = CipherMode::CBC;
    ICryptoTransform^ transform = aes->CreateEncryptor(aes->Key, aes->IV);

    FileStream^ destination = gcnew FileStream(destinationFilename, FileMode::OpenOrCreate, FileAccess::Write, FileShare::None);
    CryptoStream^ cryptoStream = gcnew CryptoStream(destination, transform, CryptoStreamMode::Write);
    FileStream^ source = gcnew FileStream(sourceFilename, FileMode::Open, FileAccess::Read, FileShare::Read);
    source->CopyTo(cryptoStream);
}
catch(Exception^ exception){Console::WriteLine(exception->Message);}
}

int main(){
srand(time(NULL));
array<Byte>^ salt = gcnew array<Byte> { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 }; // Must be at least eight bytes.  MAKE THIS SALTIER!
int iterations=rand();
EncryptFile("C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\test.txt", "C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\test1.txt", "afckingpinecone.", salt, iterations);
DecryptFile("C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\test1.txt", "C:\\Users\\test\\Desktop\\test2.txt", "afckingpinecone.", salt, iterations);
return 0;
}
```

I tested with 2 files. One .png and one plaintext. The image encrypted and decrypted fine but the text file did not. The original file contains a 15-byte ASCII string, but the encrypted and decrypted files are 0 bytes.

Comment: C# programmers tend to fall in the pit of success with the *using* statement.  You'll have to learn [C++/CLI stack semantics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177191.aspx) to find that same pit.  As-is, CryptoStream->FlushFinalBlock() is missing and you are not calling delete cryptoStream either.  So no final block.

Comment: Thanks. If you post that as an answer, I'd accept it

Comment: Just post it yourself, show the code you used, and accept it to close your question.

Answer (score 1):

You forget to close the streams, put the following lines to the end of the encrypt/decrypt functions.

```
cryptoStream->Close();
destination->Close();
```