# Generating IV and transmitting AES C#

Tags: c#, security, encryption, cryptography, aes

I'm using AESCryptoServiceProvider which is provided in .net framework with CBC cipher mode and PKCS7 Padding Mode. After going through several articles I'm bit confused about generating IV and transmission as CBC cipher mode needs unique and unpredictable.

1. AESCryptoServiceProvider provides IV when a new instance created or
   called generateIV(). Though it states random IV is generated it does
   not mention whether it uses CSPRNG or which library. Can I rely on
   using IV that is generated using generateIV() or should I use
   RNGCryptoServiceProvider? Any other best practices in IV generation?
2. When transferring the IV should it be transferred plain text or should it be [prepended](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) with cipher text? Any best practices regarding [transmission of IV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041451/good-aes-initialization-vector-practice)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041451/good-aes-initialization-vector-practice

Comment: already went through that thread. Anyway thanks. It says to prepend before cipher text and confuses. 

also check NIST's standards.
http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-38a/sp800-38a.pdf

check this as well
http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/42642/should-aes-always-give-the-same-output

Answer (score 1):

In "AESCryptoServiceProvider", generateIV() method use internally `CryptGenRandom()` of `advapi32.dll`.

Method defination of GenerateIV() :

```
public override void GenerateIV() {
            Contract.Ensures(IVValue != null && IVValue.Length == BlockSizeValue / 8);
            Contract.Assert(m_cspHandle != null);
            Contract.Assert(BlockSizeValue % 8 == 0);

            byte[] iv = new byte[BlockSizeValue / 8];
            if (!CapiNative.UnsafeNativeMethods.CryptGenRandom(m_cspHandle, iv.Length, iv)) {
                throw new CryptographicException(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
            }

            IVValue = iv;
        }
```

Signature of CryptGenRandom() :

```
/// <summary>
            ///     Fill a buffer with cryptographically random bytes
            /// </summary>
            [DllImport("advapi32", SetLastError = true)]
            [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
            public static extern bool CryptGenRandom(SafeCspHandle hProv,
                                                     int dwLen,
                                                     [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] byte[] pbBuffer);
```

Comment: Thanks for giving the insight what happens in GenerateIV() of AESCryptoServiceProvider