# C# AES Decryption code

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, aes

I have the code for string encryption/decryption with AES algorithm. Encryption works fine as expected but I could not get correct plain text when I decrypt it back. There must be something wrong in the decryption code.

I have copied the code below.
Please help with this. Thanks.

Below is the encryption and Decryption code.

```
public static class EncryptionHelper
{
    private static int BlockSize = 16;

    private static byte[] Key
    {
        get
        {
            byte[] hash = SHA1.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("BlahBlahBlah"));
            byte[] key = new byte[BlockSize];
            Array.Copy(hash, 0, key, 0, BlockSize);
            return key;
        }
    }

    private static byte[] IV
    {
        get
        {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            Random random = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < BlockSize; i++)
            {
                char ch = Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(26 * random.NextDouble() + 65)));
                builder.Append(ch);
            }
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.ToString());
        }
    }

    public static string DecodeAndDecrypt(string cipherText)
    {
        string DecodeAndDecrypt = AesDecrypt(Convert.FromBase64String(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(cipherText)));
        return (DecodeAndDecrypt);
    }

    public static string EncryptAndEncode(string plaintext)
    {
        return HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Convert.ToBase64String(AesEncrypt(plaintext))); 
    }

    public static string AesDecrypt(Byte[] inputBytes)
    {
        Byte[] outputBytes = inputBytes;

        string plaintext = string.Empty;

        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(outputBytes))
        {
            using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, GetCryptoAlgorithm().CreateDecryptor(Key, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {
                using (StreamReader srDecrypt = new StreamReader(cryptoStream))
                {
                    plaintext = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }

        return plaintext;
    }

    public static byte[] AesEncrypt(string inputText)
    {
        byte[] inputBytes = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputText); 

        for (int i = 0; i < BlockSize; i++)
        {
            inputBytes[i] ^= IV[i];
        }

        byte[] result = null;
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, GetCryptoAlgorithm().CreateEncryptor(Key, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cryptoStream.Write(inputBytes, 0, inputBytes.Length);
                cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                result = memoryStream.ToArray();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static RijndaelManaged GetCryptoAlgorithm()
    {
        RijndaelManaged algorithm = new RijndaelManaged();
        algorithm.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        algorithm.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        algorithm.KeySize = 128;
        algorithm.BlockSize = 128;
        return algorithm;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's this: `inputBytes[i] ^= IV[i];` Is it some previous attempt to encrypt manually that's not required now?

Comment: Also `IV` **may** need to be the same for encode and decode, not sure. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041451/good-aes-initialization-vector-practice

Comment: I tried skipping inputBytes[i] ^= IV[i]; But no luck

Comment: Doesn't referencing `IV` implicitly use the `get`? In that case, wouldn't you get a new random for `Decrypt`?

Comment: Note that 1) the manual XOR should not be needed 2) using SHA-1 over a password is not the same as using e.g. PBKDF2 3) the IV should really be included in the ciphertext 4) the `Random` class is not cryptographically secure and your IV doesn't contain random bytes 5) URL-encoding of Base64 is inefficient, use the base64url instead (by replacing the `/` and `+` with different characters that are URL safe) 6) the key size of AES is independent of the block size.

Comment: All the comments Maarten Bodewes made, but also I note that you are not explicitly specifying the character encoding on the decrypt.  Normally you would not read into a string like that (or I don't, anyway).  Rather, I read into a byte array and then convert the byte array to UTF8 or whatever much the same way, but reverse, that you do on your Encrypt function.

Comment: OP, in addition to all the other advice (and explicitly providing the same IV in your Encrypt and Decrypt methods is major) I wanted to add one more thing.  Your IV creation method generates an IV of 16 capital letters.  If we pretend for a moment Random were cryptographically secure (it isn't but there is an analogous method in the crypto namespace that is) then an IV should have 128 bits of entropy or 2^128 equally possible values.  Yours has 26^16 possible values, or over 7x10^15 (over 2^52) times less entropy.  Please use all byte values in your IV.

Answer (score 1):

I made a few changes and will post some source code below.  To make it work, just put 3 textBoxes on Form1 and use this code for Form1.cs.  I mentioned above I think a major issue was with how you were reading from StreamReader as a string without specifying your encoding.  My change uses BinaryReader to read as a byte array, then converts to UTF-8 string after the read.  I also deleted that XOR loop.  I think you were trying to implement CBC on your own (CBC is a sort of feedback loop of XORs) but it is not needed -- when you specify CBC mode, .NET does the CBC mode for you.  To keep my version as close as reasonably possible to yours, I did not make many more changes.  But please take some of the above comments to heart.  Don't use a simple hash when .NET provides a DeriveBytes function, for example.  Treat an IV like a paper towel -- use it once and only once, ever.  And so on.  Anyway, functional if not "best practice" code is below:

Edit:  Sorry I forgot to mention I also changed the plain text type to regular strings, deleted the HTTP-related code.  This was just to make it simpler for me to work with.  It should work just as well though with your HTTP methods as it does with regular strings.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = EncryptionHelper.EncryptAndEncode(textBox3.Text);
            textBox2.Text = EncryptionHelper.DecodeAndDecrypt(textBox1.Text);
        }
    }

    public static class EncryptionHelper
    {
        private static int BlockSize = 16;

        private static byte[] Key
        {
            get
            {
                byte[] hash = SHA1.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("BlahBlahBlah"));
                byte[] key = new byte[BlockSize];
                Array.Copy(hash, 0, key, 0, BlockSize);
                return key;
            }
        }

        private static byte[] IV
        {
            get
            {
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                Random random = new Random();
                for (int i = 0; i < BlockSize; i++)
                {
                    char ch = Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(26 * random.NextDouble() + 65)));
                    builder.Append(ch);
                }
                return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.ToString());
            }
        }

        public static string DecodeAndDecrypt(string cipherText)
        {
            byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
            string decodeAndDecrypt = AesDecrypt(cipherBytes);
            return decodeAndDecrypt;
        }

        public static string EncryptAndEncode(string plaintext)
        {
            return Convert.ToBase64String(AesEncrypt(plaintext));
        }

        public static string AesDecrypt(Byte[] inputBytes)
        {
            Byte[] outputBytes = inputBytes;

            string plaintext = string.Empty;

            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(outputBytes))
            {
                using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, GetCryptoAlgorithm().CreateDecryptor(Key, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                {
                    using (BinaryReader srDecrypt = new BinaryReader(cryptoStream))
                    {
                        outputBytes = srDecrypt.ReadBytes(inputBytes.Length);
                        plaintext = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(outputBytes);
                    }
                }
            }
            return plaintext;
        }

        public static byte[] AesEncrypt(string inputText)
        {
            byte[] inputBytes = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputText);
            byte[] result = null;
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, GetCryptoAlgorithm().CreateEncryptor(Key, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    cryptoStream.Write(inputBytes, 0, inputBytes.Length);
                    cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                    result = memoryStream.ToArray();
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        private static RijndaelManaged GetCryptoAlgorithm()
        {
            RijndaelManaged algorithm = new RijndaelManaged();
            algorithm.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            algorithm.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            algorithm.KeySize = 128;
            algorithm.BlockSize = 128;
            return algorithm;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The comments above (on the question) have the most important point: you need to use the *same IV on decrypt as used on the encrypt*, otherwise your first 16 bytes of recovered plaintext will be trashed. (CBC mode will auto-correct after the first block.)

You could simply combine the IV with the ciphertext before sending it, and then just break them apart at the other end before decrypting.

It doesn't matter if the IV is public knowledge, as long as it is cryptographically strong, random data, different for each encryption. But you need that *same* corresponding, individual IV at the other end to decrypt.

Also, as WDS points out, you should not perform that XOR operation. (But I can't see how WDS's code recovers the first 16 bytes without preserving the IV.)

Also, IMHO using a SHA1 over the password to generate the key is a security risk. You should be using PBKDF2 or similar to derive a password.

Edit: As Artjom B. points out, since your original code XOR's the IV against the first block of plaintext, you could recover the first 16 bytes by using an IV of all 0x00 bytes on decrypt. But this would only work if the ciphertext was at least two blocks (32 bytes), otherwise, you will get padding errors as this will corrupt the padding. Try using an IV of all zero bytes on your decrypt, and find out if the input is always at least 16 bytes -- you have an off-the-end-of-the-array bug anyway in your encrypt if it isn't. (You'll still have an insecure IV, but at least you will get decrypt working.)

Comment: The IV thing is strange, but believe it or not, the IV did somehow carry over in the Decrypt code as I posted it.  I agree however that it is better to explicitly communicate it over to make the code more durable.  Because I suspect that if the poster Encrypted and saved, restarted the computer and then tried to Decrypt, the first block (or is it 2 blocks with CBC?) would be destroyed because of a bad IV.

Comment: Actually, it is extremely weird.  I just put a breakpoint on the IV getter so it was hit on Encrypt and again on Decrypt.  Then, the IV is changed and "Bad Padding" happens.  But without the breakpoint, it works perfectly.  Very, very odd.  An undocumented feature of some sort.

Comment: *"But I can't see how WDS's code recovers the first 16 bytes without preserving the IV."* since the IV is applied twice on encrypt, one would only need a zero bytes IV for decryption.

Comment: Yes. I am loosing first 16 bytes even with WDS code. The encryption works perfect and i am not supposed to change the encryption code. all I need is the decryption code to get the original text back.

Comment: @Artjom B. WDS' code does not apply the IV twice. I see what you mean in the OP's code, but that would only work if the plaintext was at least 16 bytes, otherwise not having the same IV will corrupt the padding (of the first and only block of ciphertext).