# Decrypting Using AES256 - Transact SQL or C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, encryption

I apologize if this has been addressed before, but I have done some research and not been able to come up with a clear answer on my own.

I am using PHP's openSSL functions to encrypt data using 256 bit AES and storing it in an SQL database. I was surprised that (at least from my research), there did not seem to be an easy way to decrypt this data (there is in MySql after all).

Perhaps I am simply overlooking something incredibly obvious but how can I decrypt this data so that I can display it to trusted users? I can use either C# or Transact SQL to perform this task, but, to my surprise, have yet to figure how to accomplish it with either.

Again, I do not mean to waste anybody's time or just have someone 'feed' me the answers, but I have looked into without success. As such, I really appreciate any help.

Comment: You say there is no easy way to decript it, do you mean in C# or what?

Comment: Check this site. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/chinnasrihari/data-encryption-and-decryption-in-sql-server-2008/

Comment: how do you encrypt the data?

Comment: The data is encrypted using AES256 through PHP's openSSL functions. Yes, decrypting by PHP would make sense, but it will not work for my purpose. I am struggling to find a way to do it in either C# or Transact SQL. Honestly, I would prefer to do it in C#, but could not find classes or methods that support AES256 (though again, I could be overlooking it). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server you can load keys into the server to do it.  Or you can write custom code in C# and load that in as a procedure.

Regardless the hard part is managing your key for encryption.  The following page has a reasonable start on how it works in TSQL.  [MSDN Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174361.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

AES with a 256-bit key has a few implementation in C#. Just search SO for [C#] AES, one [SO example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32281151/451475), also [MSDN AES](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aes(v=vs.110).aspx).

Note that a lot of older implementations go by the name Rijndael which is a super set of AES. Be careful, Rijndael supports several block sizes so if you need AES select Rijndael a 128-bit block size and a 256-bit key (the key size is often selected automatically by the supplied key).