# Error splitting an array into two

Tags: c#, arrays

So I need to cut off the first 16 bytes from my byte array. I followed another post I saw on Stack Overflow to use the following code:

```
//split message into iv and encrypted bytes
byte[] iv = new byte[16];
byte[] workingHash = new byte[rage.Length - 16];

//put first 16 bytes into iv
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
{
    iv[i] = rage[i];
}

Buffer.BlockCopy(rage, 16, workingHash, 0, rage.Length);
```

What we are trying here is to cut off the first 16 bytes from the `byte[] rage` and put the rest into `byte[] workingHash`

The error occurs at `Buffer.BlockCopy(rage, 16, workingHash, 0, rage.Length);`

> Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the number of elements from index to the end of the source collection.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: `workingHash` is rage.Length - 16, so you cant copy `rage.Length` bytes.  this looks like it is missing a windows phone tag

Comment: Did you debug your own code? Seems a issue trivial for someone dealing with AES encryption.

Comment: Of courseI debugged it... Anyways... fixed.

Comment: It is also possible (and more common)  to store the IV to the raw stream by itself so you can use stream.Write/Read with it and not have to go thru all that and whatever you are doing to prepend the IV to it when encrypting. see http://stackoverflow.com/q/8041451/1070452

Answer (score 1):

The problem is trivial: `Buffer.BlockCopy`'s last argument requires the correct number of bytes to be copied, which (taking the starting index into account) may not exceed the array's bounds ([docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Hence the code should look like this, avoiding any `for` cycles:

```
Buffer.BlockCopy(rage, 0, iv, 0, 16);
Buffer.BlockCopy(rage, 16, workingHash, 0, rage.Length - 16);
```

Notice the “`- 16`” at the second line, fixing the original code. The first line replaces the `for` cycle for the sake of consistency.

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume `rage` is a `byte` array of length 20:

```
var rage = new byte[20]
{
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20
};
```

After `byte[] iv = new byte[16];`, `iv` will contain:

```
{ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
```

After `byte[] workingHash = new byte[rage.Length - 16];`, `workingHash` will contain:

```
{ 0, 0, 0, 0 }
```

After the `for` loop `iv` is:

```
{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 }
```

You need:

```
Buffer.BlockCopy(rage, 16, workingHash, 0, rage.Length - 16);
```

Copy `rage.Length - 16` (4) elements from `rage`'s 16th element (which is 17) to `workingHash` starting from the 0th element.

The result:

```
{ 17, 18, 19, 20 }
```

By the way there is a very readable way, probably not as fast as copying arrays, but worth mentioning:

```
var firstSixteenElements = rage.Take(16).ToArray();
var remainingElements = rage.Skip(16).ToArray();
```

Answer (score -1):

Fixed:

```
                //split message into iv and encrypted bytes
                byte[] iv = new byte[16];
                byte[] workingHash = new byte[rage.Length - 16];

                //put first 16 bytes into iv
                for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
                {
                    iv[i] = rage[i];
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < rage.Length - 16; i++)
                {
                    workingHash[i] = rage[i + 16];
                }
```

Comment: Bad fix. Better would be to understand the bug and keep the BlockCopy call which is much better code. The fix was just a `-16` somewhere. Don't rewrite hoping the bug goes away!