# Junk bytes before payload in C# UTF8 to AES to Base64 conversion

Tags: c#, encryption, utf-8, cryptography, base64

I have been trying to implement proper IV practice in methods to encrypt and decrypt a UTF-8 string with AES which is then returned as a Base64 string.  Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041451/good-aes-initialization-vector-practice) question as a reference, I have prepended the generated IV to the byte array before the Base64 conversion.  I'm having an issue where the decrypt method returns the UTF-8 string with exactly fifty characters of random junk (encryption artifacts?).  I don't believe the issue is with the encryption because the decrypt method does consistently return the encrypted string.  I think the problem is with one of the other conversion steps but I'm having trouble seeing where this might be coming from. Any help would be wildly appreciated.

**Encrypt method**

```
    public static string EncryptString(string input, string key)
    {
        using (var aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
        {

            aes.Key = System.Convert.FromBase64String(key);
            aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

            byte[] rawData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input); 
            // IV is the 16 byte AES Initialization Vector 
            aes.GenerateIV();

            using (var encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV)) 
            {
                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    ms.Write(aes.IV, 0, aes.IV.Length); // aes.IV.Length should be 16
                    using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        cs.Write(rawData, 0, rawData.Length);
                        cs.FlushFinalBlock();
                    }
                    byte[] encryptedData = ms.ToArray();

                    // this will hold the IV prepended to the encrypted data
                    byte[] output = new byte[aes.IV.Length + encryptedData.Length];

                    Array.Copy(aes.IV, output, aes.IV.Length); // save the iv
                    Array.Copy(encryptedData, 0, output, aes.IV.Length, encryptedData.Length);    // save the data

                    // now encode the whole thing as base 64
                    return System.Convert.ToBase64String(output);

                }
            }

        }

    }
```

**Decrypt method**

```
    public static string DecryptString(string input, string key)
    {

        using (var aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            aes.Key = Convert.FromBase64String(key);
            aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

            byte[] rawData = Convert.FromBase64String(input);
            byte[] IV = new byte[16];  // aes.IV.Length should be 16

            Array.Copy(rawData, IV, IV.Length);
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var cs = new CryptoStream(ms, aes.CreateDecryptor(aes.Key, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                {
                    using (var binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(cs))
                    {
                        binaryWriter.Write(rawData,IV.Length ,rawData.Length - IV.Length);
                    }
                }
                return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
            }
        }
    }
```

**My test**

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string payload = "My super secret string";
        string key = "tR4mPn7mBQ8G6HWusyFnGk/gqdd/enWiUTr7YbhNrJg=";

        Console.WriteLine(payload);
        Console.WriteLine(key);

        Console.WriteLine("");
        string encrypted = EncryptString(payload, key);
        Console.WriteLine(encrypted);

        Console.WriteLine("");
        string decrypted = DecryptString(encrypted, key);
        Console.WriteLine(decrypted);

        Console.WriteLine(decrypted.Length.ToString() + " " + encrypted.Length.ToString());

        Console.ReadKey();

    }
```

Edit to add - this is an example of the output:

�XQ��=F�]�D�?�My super secret string

Comment: Examine the output as hex and you will see the issue, Base64 is for computers, not humans.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are writing the IV to the output twice in `EncryptString`. First you have:

```
ms.Write(aes.IV, 0, aes.IV.Length); // aes.IV.Length should be 16
```

which is the start of `encryptedData`. You then copy the IV and `encryptedData` (which already includes the IV) into a new byte array:

```
// this will hold the IV prepended to the encrypted data
byte[] output = new byte[aes.IV.Length + encryptedData.Length];

Array.Copy(aes.IV, output, aes.IV.Length); // save the iv
Array.Copy(encryptedData, 0, output, aes.IV.Length, encryptedData.Length);    // save the data
```

This doubling of the IV is what is causing the extra bytes.

You don’t need to do the second copying. Just convert `encryptedData` to base 64 directly and return that:

```
return System.Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedData);
```

Comment: This is correct. I figured it was a simple mistake.  My tired Friday eyes just couldn't catch it.