# How do you create SHA-2 and AES encrypted string to use in HTTP request header in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, aes, sha

I am trying to write client code that requests for information from an external API over the web.

The API is simple enough (to me) except for the stipulations of how to **generate the authorisation key**.
First some context:
There are 6 string values required to start with:

- token
- password
- devId
- salt
- orgId
- givenKey

Now for the encryption stuff. First up SHA2.

```
hashedString = SHA2(token + password + devId)
```

Followed by AES.

```
authKey = AES(salt + orgId + "=" + hashedString)
```

The AES parameters are specified as follows:

- Mode = ECB
- Padding = PKCS5Padding
- Secret Key = givenKey

My problem is that I know next to nothing about cryptography.

Below is the code I have attempting to accomplish the above.

```
// Generate Authorisation key
            byte[] fieldsBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(token + password + devId);
            byte[] keyBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(secretKey);
            SHA512 shaM = new SHA512Managed();
            string hashedFields = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(shaM.ComputeHash(fieldsBytes));
            byte[] encryptedBytes = EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(salt + orgId + "=" + hashedfields,
                keyBytes, keyBytes);
            string encryptedString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(encryptedBytes);


private byte[] EncryptStringToBytes_Aes(string plainText, byte[] Key, byte[] IV)
        {
            // Check arguments.
            if (plainText == null || plainText.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
            if (Key == null || Key.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Key");
            if (IV == null || IV.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("IV");
            byte[] encrypted;

            // Create an Aes object
            // with the specified key and IV.
            using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
            {
                aesAlg.Key = Key;
                aesAlg.IV = IV;
                aesAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                aesAlg.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;

                // Create an encryptor to perform the stream transform.
                ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor();

                // Create the streams used for encryption.
                using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                        {
                            //Write all data to the stream.
                            swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                        }
                        encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                    }
                }
            }

            // Return the encrypted bytes from the memory stream.
            return encrypted;
        }
```

This code gets a "401" from the external service.

My first issue is that there does **not** seem to be a NET method named **SHA2**. The closest I could find is SHA512 and I am not sure if SHA512 is a .NET implementation of SHA2.

Secondly, padding for AES has been specified as PKCS5Padding but again the closest (naming-wise) I could find is **PKCS7** which I am **not** sure about how similar it is to **PKCS5**.

There is also the matter of an **Initialisation Vector (IV)**, which the AES parameters don't specify but I see C# AES examples including. In the code, I have set it to have the same value as the Key (which I believe
is what the API calls "secret key") out of sheer desperation but I have tried making the request without setting IV to any value and still get back a 401.

I should probably also mention that I am using **ASCII** encoding to convert to-and-from bytes because I first tried using **UTF8** but when it came to actually making the HTTP request, I was getting an exception
saying that header values (remember we are generating an authorisation key that will be tucked in a HTTP request header) should only be encoded in ASCII.

Any help pointing me in the right direction will be immensely appreciated as I am woefully out of my depth with this cryptography stuff.

Comment: I'm assuming that you don't have control over the external API here?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have absolutely no control over it whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to get it to work.

A big part of the problem was that API documentation did not specify that hashedString has to
be composed of **hexadecimal** characters.
It also didn't say that authKey should be a **base64** string.
I don't know if this is so standard that it goes without saying but knowing this could have 
saved me hours of agony. I was converting the hashed/encrypted bytes back to ASCII
and much of it was unprintable characters that were causing the server to send back
a HTTP response with status 400 BAD_REQUEST.

It also required hashedString to be hashed using SHA256 but the documentation does not mention it.
Thanks to @[Nate Barbettini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3191599/nate-barbettini)'s answer for steering me in the right direction on this.

Also, it appears that AES ECB mode does **not require** an initialisation vector unlike other
modes like CBC so I didn't specify an IV.

For padding I specified PKCS7 (again thanks to @[Nate Barbettini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3191599/nate-barbettini) for that).

With that here's the code that finally worked out for me.

```
 string hashedFields = ComputeSha256HashHex(authToken + password + devId);

 string encryptedString = AesEncryptToBase64String(saltString + orgId + "=" + hashedFields, secretKey);

        private string AesEncryptToBase64String(string plainText, string key)
        {
            // Convert string arguments into byte arrays
            byte[] keyBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);
            byte[] plainTextBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(plainText);

            // Check arguments.
            if (plainText == null || plainText.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
            if (key == null || key.Length <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
            byte[] encrypted;

            // Create an Aes object
            // with the specified key and IV.
            using (Aes aesAlg = Aes.Create())
            {
                aesAlg.Key = keyBytes;
                aesAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
                aesAlg.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;

                // Create an encryptor to perform the stream transform.
                ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor();

                // Create the streams used for encryption.
                using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                        {
                            //Write all data to the stream.
                            swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                        }
                        encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
                    }
                }
            }

            // Return encrypted bytes as Base 64 string
            return Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted);
        }


        private string ComputeSha256HashHex(string plainText)
        {
            using (SHA256 sha256Hash = SHA256.Create())
            {
                // ComputeHash - returns byte array  
                byte[] bytes = sha256Hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText));

                // Convert byte array to a string   
                return BytesToHexString(bytes);
            }
        }


        private string BytesToHexString(byte[] bytes)
        {
            // Convert byte array to a string   
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
            {
                builder.Append(bytes[i].ToString("x2"));
            }
            return builder.ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't worry, crypto can feel overwhelmingly complicated. I think you're close.

1. [SHA2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) is a *family* of hash functions. In practice, "SHA2" usually means SHA2-256 or occasionally SHA2-512. My guess is that your external API is probably using the more common SHA2-256.
2. [This answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9043/what-is-the-difference-between-pkcs5-padding-and-pkcs7-padding) on crypto.stackexchange explains that PKCS#5 is essentially a subset of PKCS#7. I'd be willing to bet that the API you're calling made the same mistake described in that answer and should really be calling it `PKCS7Padding`. Your code is fine!
3. The IV isn't the same thing as the secret key (or just the "key" for AES). The IV [should be random](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8041580/3191599) for every encryption run. You aren't supposed to derive it from the input plaintext or the input key. Fortunately, `AesCryptoServiceProvider.GenerateIV()` will generate one for you. It's up to you to **prepend** it to your output stream, though.
4. Using `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes()` to get the plaintext and secret key bytes makes sense to me. I don't think that's causing a problem.

Stealing from [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56488564/3191599) to a similar question (go give them a vote!), I'd try code like this:

```
static byte[] AesEncrypt(byte[] data, byte[] key)
{
    if (data == null || data.Length <= 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException($"{nameof(data)} cannot be empty");
    }

    if (key == null || key.Length != AesKeySize)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(key)} must be length of {AesKeySize}");
    }

    using (var aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider
    {
        Key = key,
        Mode = CipherMode.CBC,
        Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7
    })
    {
        aes.GenerateIV();
        var iv = aes.IV;
        using (var encrypter = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, iv))
        using (var cipherStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var tCryptoStream = new CryptoStream(cipherStream, encrypter, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            using (var tBinaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(tCryptoStream))
            {
                // prepend IV to data
                cipherStream.Write(iv);
                tBinaryWriter.Write(data);
                tCryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
            }
            var cipherBytes = cipherStream.ToArray();

            return cipherBytes;
        }
    }
}
```

Unless there's something else weird going on with this API, I'd guess it's probably #3 above that is causing your request to fail.

Comment: I have already left the office for the day. I will definitely try this first thing once I am back in the office but I must say you've already made it look a lot less intimidating.  :) Thank you very much.

Comment: I finally found a solution and posted it. Thanks for all your help in steering me towards the right direction.

Comment: @SteveS Glad you got it sorted!